# Tuning logistic regression with class_weight hyperparameter for an imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, tuning

I just have an imbalanced dataset, and now I am at the point where I am tuning my model, logistic regression.

As I understood, class_weight parameter helps us dealing with these kind of datasets, and when doing model tuning you can use different weights to get a better performance.

What I am not sure about is how can choose different weights to tune my model according to the dataset that I am using.

I am using this well-known dataset, adult income found on kaggle.

So I am looking to get different weights for my two classes (0 and 1) - if income is <= 50k or > 50k a year. For example , we know that weights can be in this form : {class_label (0 and 1) : weight (how can I find, deduce different weights for each label here?)}.

Some examples would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What is the performance criterion that is most important for your application?

Comment: [Much has been written about why class imbalance is much less of an issue than many believe.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any).

Comment: @DikranMarsupialnot sure what you mean by performance criterion. But what I need to do is just predict people with income above 50 k. I am pretty new to machine learning and I am not sure what exactly you are asking :)) Sorry.

Comment: @Dave I will have a look, thanks

Comment: @Daniel For a performance criterion, what do you want to get out of the model? High accuracy? High accuracy of a particular class? High accuracy of a particular class without going below a certain level of accuracy for another class? Do you have values that you can assign as profit/loss to correct/incorrect classifications? (Responses like “accuracy”, “precision”, and “recall” are what I expect, but maybe you have something else in mind, and that is fine (arguably preferable).)

Comment: @Dave A good accuracy; I am looking for a small gap between accuracies of train set and test set, which means that the model is doing what is supposed to do, as far as I understood so far, and yeah, I use recall, precision etc (the classification report) for evaluation. The thing is that I have tested it already, but I have used some weights which I don’t from an example.

Comment: Why use weights if you just want high accuracy? Weights are typically used to increase the penalty for missing instances of the minority class at the expense of penalizing misses of the dominant class, lowering accuracy to improve sensitivity to the minority class. // When you have huge imbalance, you can get accuracy score that look very high even though all you do is classify everything as the majority class.

Comment: @Dave I've used this approach https://machinelearningmastery.com/cost-sensitive-logistic-regression/

Comment: @Daniel Misconceptions abound when it comes to class imbalance. What do *you* want to achieve by doing machine learning?

Comment: @Dave this is in regards to my coursework for uni. So I am just trying to approach an imbalanced dataset. And now I am at the point where I am tuning for logistic regression, that’s it

Comment: "I am looking for a small gap between accuracies of train set and test set, which means that the model is doing what is supposed to do" this is not correct.  Quite often optimal generalisation performance is obtained for a model with zero error on the training set, especially when there are a large number of features.  If you are interested in performance, just look at the test set performance, if it isn't good, *then* look at the training set error as one means of diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @Daniel if it is coursework that must be clearly stated in the question, as otherwise there is a possibility that asking questions here would be considered plagiarism or collusion (it would at my university).

Comment: The only thing that I just want to understand is how are these weights of a class deduced.

Comment: I am just going to use other hyperparameters for tuning.